# How to estimate and interpret Cross-Level Interaction and Conditional Effect in SPSS?

Tags: spss, interaction, multilevel-analysis, conditional-expectation

In my model I estimate the cross level interaction between:

micro level variabel: hours spent on paid work (0 to 84 hours)

macro level variable: income compensation for parental leave
0 = no compensation, 1 = some compensation, 2 = high compensation

on Y men's hours spend on housework.

I use a ordinal coding of 0-2 for compensation whereby it is shown that the interaction effect is significant at a level of 10 percent.

As you can see below, the main effect of time spend in paid work on Y is -0.071 if compensation = 0.

QUESTION 1:
How do I test the conditional effect for compensation = 2 in SPSS?

Question 2:
is it always necessary to report the conditional effect for the min and max in order to define that there is an interaction effect?

[image]